Using Lie's theorem to prove $\det A=\det B$
I am trying to prove that if $ A^2 + B^2 = 2AB $, then $\det(A) = \det(B) $.
I understand that this could be solved by proving that $ A $ and $ B $ share the same root subspace. However, I recently received a hint suggesting that this could be proved using Lie's theorem and Engel's theorem.
The hint indicates that the Lie algebra $ L $, generated by $ A $ and $ B $, is nilpotent because every matrix in $ L $ is nilpotent, which implies that $ L $ is solvable. By applying Lie's theorem, $ A $ and $ B $ can be simultaneously triangularized, which should then lead to the desired result.
I was able to prove that $ [A, B] = (A - B)^2 = C $ is nilpotent, but I am struggling with $ [A, C] $ and other elements in $ L $. I am unsure how to compute these and how they fit into the overall structure of the proof.
Could someone help clarify how to proceed with calculating these commutators or provide further insight into the structure of the Lie algebra $ L $?

The matrices in $L$ need not be nilpotent, take $A=B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, or $A=B=I$.

I have given an elementary solution (without using Lie algebra) in an answer to another question.

See also here for a solution. The key idea for using a Lie algebra is given in this post.  In their language, $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are simultaneously triangulable (Lie), and $Y^2$ is nilpotent.
